# Intersects without clipping input vector layer

Tags: qgis, clip, grids-graticules

I have two layers, one with a fishnet grid of a country, and then the borders of the country. I would like to get a shapefile with all the features of this grid that intersect with the borders of the country. Using intersect or clip, they all cut the initial grid to the borders.

So I am getting:

[image: clip/intersect result]

But my goal is to get this:

[image: Paint skills]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Select by Expression on the grid layer to select grid features that intersect the country.

> intersects( $geometry,  geometry( get_feature( 'countrylayer', 'namefield', 'countryname')))

Customize the selection expression for your data as follows:

- countrylayer -> substitute the name of the country layer
- namefield -> substitute the name of the field that contains country names
- countryname -> substitute the name of your country

[image]

Then save the selection by right clicking on the grid layer name in the layer panel > save as... > save only selected features.

[image]